# Getting from Oxford to Saunderton (near High Wycombe), by public transport, before 9am?

Tags: uk, public-transport, oxford

In a few weeks, I'll need to get from Oxford to the lovely village of Saunderton, which is between Princes Risborough and High Wycombe. I'll need to get there by 9am, and by public transport.

If I was to do the same journey in 2016, then it'd be very easy. I'd hop on a Chiltern Trains service from Oxford towards London Marylebone via Bicester, and change at Princes Risborough. Sadly though, the [upgraded and new lines that make up the Evergreen 3 Project](http://www.chiltern-evergreen3.co.uk/) are still underway, and it's a year until you'll be able to get a train from Kidlington through Bicester towards London, and 2016 until the full Oxford - Bicester - London route is (re-)opened.

Now, because of said line upgrades and new line construction, I can't even hop on a train from Oxford to Bicester Town, walk a short way across Bicester, and take a train from Bicester North down to Saunderton, since the line is closed for upgrades.

In theory, I could take a train from Oxford into London, walk / tube from Paddington to Marylebone, then a train out to Saunderton. Surely there must be an easier way though...?

So, starting from Oxford, and needing to get to Saunderton before 9am, using only buses and trains (such as there are), is it possible to do the journey by public transport without having to trek into London and back out again?

(If it wasn't for a meeting, with an overnight after it, I'd be tempted to hop on my bike and cycle there via the [Phoenix Trail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27110/where-are-the-start-points-for-the-phoenix-trail-between-princes-risborough-th) and [National Cycle Route 57](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Cycle_Route_57). I'm not sure it'd work so well cycling it with a laptop and a cabin sized rolling suitcase...!)

Comment: Use this http://www.transportdirect.info

Answer (score 2):

A quick search on [travelinesoutheast.org.uk](http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/) gives you several options:

[image: Screenshot of search results (transcribed below)]

```
    Depart   Arrive   Changes   Max journey time   Trip Summary
1.  0643     0817     1         01:34              walk, coach, bus, walk
2.  0658     0852     2         01:54              walk, bus, walk, train, train, walk
3.  0728     0922     2         01:54              walk, bus, train, walk, bus, walk
4.  0752     0929     1         01:37              walk, coach, walk, train, walk
5.  0822     0955     1         01:33              walk, coach, walk, train, walk
6.  0828     0955     2         01:27              walk, bus, bus, walk, train, walk
7.  0828     1000     1         01:32              walk, bus, bus, walk
8.  0936     1105     1         01:29              walk, bus, walk, train, walk
9.  0956     1131     1         01:35              walk, bus, walk, train, walk
```

(none of which are particularly pleasing). The one that gets you there for about the right time is:

[image: Screenshot of travel options (transcribed below)]

> ## Option 2
>
> **0658: Oxford (Oxon)**
> **walk:** From the centre of Oxford (Oxon) walk for about 2 mins
>
> **0700: Oxford City Centre, Turl Street, Stop L1 (on High Street) [SMS: oxfgapmd]**
> **bus:** Take **Arriva the Shires & Essex** Bus **280**
> towards Aylesbury, Bus Station
> and get off at
>
> **0754: Haddenham, adj Railway Station (on Station Forecourt)**
> **walk:** Walk about 4 mins to
>
> **0811: Haddenham & Thame Parkway Rail Station**
> **train:** Take **Chiltern Railways** Train
> towards London Marylebone Rail Station
> and get off at
>
> **0818: Princes Risborough Rail Station**
> **walk:** Then transfer to
>
> **0838: Princes Risborough Rail Station**
> **train:** Take **Chiltern Railways** Train
> towards London Marylebone Rail Station
> and get off at
>
> **0843: Saunderton Rail Staion**
> **walk:** Then walk for about 9 mins to the centre of Saunderton
>
> **0852: Saunderton**

So a bus and two trains and a fair bit of walking.

Personally, for that kind of distance I’d order a cab. That’d be more expensive but much, much more convenient and **faster**! There’ll be plenty outside of Oxford train station at that time of the morning. Give yourself plenty of time to allow for the rush hour traffic, which is not pleasant in Oxford.